# How to replace string with newline in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column in table where it stores the value as a string but in following format:

```
column_value =([tag1 = 'abc']) and ([tag2 = 'xyz']) and ([tag3=123])
```

and I want output in following format:

```
    tag1='abc'
    tag2='xyz'
    tag3=123
```

Can it be done using any regexp expression in oracle?

Comment: Why do you store that data thus at all? Either have three columns tag1, tag2, tag3 or have another table with one row per tag. Then you don't have to muddle through with string operations anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about regexp, but a few `replace`s do the job:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select q'[([tag1 = 'abc']) and ([tag2 = 'xyz']) and ([tag3=123])]' from dual)
  4  select replace(replace(replace(col, '([', ''), '])'), ' and ', chr(10)) result
  5  from test;

RESULT
----------------------------------
tag1 = 'abc'
tag2 = 'xyz'
tag3=123


SQL>
```

---

As you use SQL Developer, you'll have to double-click the result, click the pencil button and see the result:

[image]

Comment: It is replacing the brackets only but not addign the newline

Comment: It is (as demonstrated). Which tool do you use?

Comment: I use sql developer

Comment: Aah ok got it .  I thought it should be visible in result also. Anyways which tool do you use ?

Comment: Tool I used in this demo is SQL*Plus.